# how to define special Filed in models Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am going to write a Django custom Field model to store CardNums. The Field must meet the following requirements:

1. The stored value should never be fully visible - given a CardNum like "GR96 0810 0010 0000 0123 4567 890", the value should be displayed as "---7890" everywhere
   ?
2. Superusers should be able to see the full value when needed.

how can I handle it in the model this availability in the model?

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I used from_db_value but I don't know how to say to model use superuser in that